# Add video on the fly in playlist m3u8

Tags: ffmpeg, video, streaming

How can I change the playlist on the fly with ffmpeg? I tried with a concat but it doesn't work. I then saw that ffmpeg takes into account m3u8 playlists, but while testing I realize that adding a video to the current playlist crashes the stream.
Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

All my videos are pre-encoded in the same format.
Thanks in advance!